# Adding multiple url sources to one list display [ReactJs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

so I am currently working on an admin control panel for a page that displays a list of card. The cards contain details passed on from a local API that is hosted with a range of data such as "id", "title", "URL" and "ThumbnailUrl" and this is obtained from "localhost:0000/videos".

So I have a module, one that creates the Card called HelpCard.tsx and the code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../help/HelpCardTwo.css";
import "../help/HelpList";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";
import spinner from "../help/spinner.gif";
import placeholder from "../help/placeholder.jpeg";

interface Props {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  deleteProduct: (id: any) => void;
  editProduct: (id: any, title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) => void;
}

interface State {
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  id: string;
  url: string;
  imageLoading?: boolean;
  tooManyRequests?: boolean;
}

export default class HelpCard extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    url: "",
    id: "",
    title: "",
    imageLoading: true,
    tooManyRequests: false,
    thumbnail: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { url, title, thumbnail } = this.props;
    const id = url.split("/")[url.split("/").length - 2];

    this.setState({
      url,
      id,
      title,
      thumbnail,
      imageLoading: true,
      tooManyRequests: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const isThumbnail = this.state.thumbnail;
    const adminhelpcard = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="cards">
          <article className="card card--2">
            <div className="card__info-hover"></div>
            <div className="card__img">
              {this.state.imageLoading ? <img src={placeholder} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}></img> : null}
              <img
                className="Sprite"
                onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
                onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: false })}
                src={this.state.thumbnail}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="card__info">
              <span className="card__category">{this.state.title}</span>
              <div className="cardButtons">
                <Popup trigger={<button className="btn blue-outline">Edit</button>} modal position="left top">
                  <form
                    onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                    id="videoCardEdit"
                    style={{ width: "auto", height: "auto" }}>
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <label>Title:</label>
                        <input
                          className="input"
                          style={{ width: "100%" }}
                          name="videoCardTitle"
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
                          }}
                          value={this.state.title}></input>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <label>URL:</label>
                        <input
                          className="input"
                          style={{ width: "100%" }}
                          name="videoCardURL"
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            this.setState({ url: e.target.value });
                          }}
                          value={this.state.url}></input>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <label>Thumbnail URL:</label>
                        <input
                          className="input"
                          style={{ width: "100%" }}
                          name="videoCardThumbnail"
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            this.setState({ thumbnail: e.target.value });
                          }}
                          value={this.state.thumbnail}></input>
                      </div>
                      <br></br>
                    </div>
                    <button
                      className="btn blue-outline"
                      style={{
                        float: "left"
                      }}
                      onClick={() =>
                        this.props.editProduct(this.props.id, this.state.title, this.state.url, this.state.thumbnail)
                      }
                      id="btn blue-outline">
                      confirm
                    </button>
                  </form>
                </Popup>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(this.props.id)} className="btn blue-outline">
                  Delete
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I then also have HelpList.tsx that has the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HelpCard from "./HelpCard";
import "../help/HelpCard.css";
import axios from "axios";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";

interface State {
  url: string;
  title: string;
  adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard[];
  error: null;
  response: {};
  thumbnail: string;
}

interface SingleAdminHelpCard {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}

interface Props {}

export default class HelpList extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    title: "",
    thumbnail: "",
    id: "",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/videos/",
    adminhelpcard: [],
    itemsCountPerPage: 1,
    activePage: 1,
    error: null,
    response: {}
  };

  loadAdminHelpCard = () => {
    axios
      .get(this.state.url)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          const adminhelpcard = prevState.adminhelpcard;
          return {
            adminhelpcard: [...prevState.adminhelpcard, ...res.data],
            url: res.data.next
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  static props: any;

  async componentDidMount() {
    const apiVideoUrl = "http://localhost:3000/videos/";
    const apiManualUrl = "http://localhost:3000/manuals/";

    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ adminhelpcard: res.data });
    fetch(apiVideoUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            adminhelpcard: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
    fetch(apiManualUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            adminhelpcard: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  deleteProduct(id: any) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;

    const apiVideoUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;
    const apiManualUrl = `http://localhost:3000/manuals/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "DELETE"
    };

    fetch(apiVideoUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
    fetch(apiManualUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );

    console.log(this.state.id);
  }

  editProduct(id: any, title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
    const apiVideoUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;
    const apiManualUrl = `http://localhost:3000/manuals/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        url,
        thumbnail
      })
    };

    fetch(apiVideoUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
    fetch(apiManualUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.adminhelpcard);
    return (
      <div>
        <React.Fragment>
          {this.state.adminhelpcard ? (
            <div className="row">
              <InfiniteScroll
                pageStart={1}
                loadMore={this.loadAdminHelpCard}
                hasMore={this.state.url ? true : false}
                threshold={0}
                loader={
                  <div className="loader" key={0}>
                    Loading ...
                  </div>
                }>
                {this.state.adminhelpcard.map((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard, i) => (
                  <HelpCard
                    id={adminhelpcard.id}
                    key={adminhelpcard.id + i}
                    title={adminhelpcard.title}
                    url={adminhelpcard.url}
                    thumbnail={adminhelpcard.thumbnail}
                    deleteProduct={this.deleteProduct.bind(this)}
                    editProduct={this.editProduct.bind(this)}
                  />
                ))}
              </InfiniteScroll>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <h1>Loading Cards</h1>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So I created these two classes to obtain all the information from localhost:0000/videos before realizing theres also localhost:0000/texts which also send the same data such as "Id, title, URL, thumbnailUrl". How can I go about loading all the cards from both urls simultaneosly? The list now only seems to bring in /texts cards and not both together.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to use a `Promise.all(getVideos(),getTexts())`. Assuming `getVideos()` and `getTexts()` are methods that are returning promises like so:

```
async function getVideos() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/videos/')
  return await res.json();
}

async function getText() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/texts/')
  return await res.json();
}

Promise.all(getVideos(), getTexts()).then(data = {
 const [ videos, texts ] = data;
 // all data arrived at the same time
})
```

Comment: So I'd put this in my HelpList module?

Comment: yea in your `componentDidMount()`. Currently, it looks like you are doing two fetch calls after another. What you want is for them to finish at the same time right? Then you can just have one call to `setState({ videos, texts })`

Comment: I tried to call the URL's twice for each function similar to the componentDidMount(), will i only need to change that? or also the editProduct, deleteProduct etc? I'm unsure of the exact change i'd need

Comment: I posted a new answer above, hopefully that clears things up?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine your `componentDidMount` to look like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const apiVideoUrl = "http://localhost:3000/videos/";
    const apiManualUrl = "http://localhost:3000/manuals/";

    const getVideos = async() => {
      return await axios.get(apiVideoUrl);
    }

    const getManuals = async() => {
      return await axios.get(apiManualUrl);
    }

    try {
      const [videos,  manuals] = await Promise.all(getVideos(), getManuals());
    // render to state setState({ prop: ? })
    } catch(err) {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  }
```

not sure why you have two fetch calls in edit and delete, it looks like the calls are overwriting each other?

Comment: It's because I was trying to call the data from both sources? because previously I just used to call "const apiVideoUrl = "http://localhost:3000/videos/";"

Comment: I get the following error from getManuals() : const getManuals: () => Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>
Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)

and error is not defined

Comment: Also would I change my state for the class? as theres            
 " url: "http://localhost:3000/videos/" and now  I have more than one url